# Distribution of dice sums

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I want to study the distributions of sums of dice, especially what happens when the number of dice increases

And for that I know that I have to create a function using a list of numbers and an integer n as arguments and allowing to produce another list of numbers corresponding to the sum of n numbers, a list of [image]
if the input list of numbers is {xi}
and they asked to use a while loop to iterate through the list of numbers.

If anyone has any ideas that would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'd just say: CLT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is a fun experiment, If i understand your question correctly you are looking for distribution of dice sums with variation in dice counts.

Below is the code to get you started

```
import random
def simulatediceplay(num_of_dice):
  sum = 0
  for i in range(num_of_dice):
    sum +=random.randint(1,6)
  return sum

def generateplay(num_of_dice,num_of_runs):
  lst = []
  for i in range(num_of_runs):
    lst.append(simulatediceplay(num_of_dice))
  return lst

lst = generateplay(4,1000)
import seaborn as sns
sns.distplot(lst);
```

Output (for simulation of 1000 dice throws of 4 dices :

[image: 4 dice throw]

Output (for simulation of 1000 dice throws of 8 dices :
[image]

Below code can help you generate how the stddev and mean changes for the different dice counts

```
import statistics
listdice =[]
listdev = []
listmean = []
for i in range(1,20):
  lst = generateplay(i,1000)
  listdice.append(i)
  listdev.append(statistics.stdev(lst))
  listmean.append(statistics.mean(lst))

# draw lineplot
sns.lineplot(x=listdice, y=listmean)
# draw lineplot
sns.lineplot(x=listdice, y=listdev)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your answer which are of great help to me. I thank you very much! this is exactly what was asked for in the exercise! :)